# Why do we need an Object Relational Mapper?

Tags: java, hibernate

I bought a book on Hibernate.  I wanted to learn on what Hibernate is and what is Object Relational Mapping in general.

Harnessing Hibernate has good topics on Hibernate and I do think that I am able to write simple mapping classes now. My problem is, I think I am way ahead on the Hibernate but I really don't know why we need one.

The book explains Hibernate clearly but I think I am at lost because it does not discuss why we need Hibernate and an ORM.

Comment: Edited my post apart from the wikipedia link to give a simple explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too would suggest starting at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Relational_Mapping).

From there, follow the links at the bottom.

To provide a short answer: An ORM is used to abstract from the data storage, usually a database. This can serve multiple purposes, among those:

- Application programmers can add and
  maintain functionality of the
  software without in-depth knowledge
  of the database (you can write your
  code in Java, not in SQL).
- It takes away the pitfalls of having
  to assemble your SQL statements as
  strings and therefore eliminates a
  huge source of errors.
- Database optimization is independent
  from business logic. This ensures
  better maintainability.  The
  optimization can either be done by
  the ORM ( via configuration files) or
  directly in the database (by manually
  adding index tables and/or query
  caches). Both will not take place in
  the actual program code.
- Data providers can more easily be
  exchanged, because the ORM usually
  offers drivers for multiple
  databases, so that the same
  functional logic will work with
  different products and vendors.

Comment: So does this goes to say,  that I still need to perform my ERD diagramming/normalization/indexing upfront so that I could derive my base tables and then afterwhich I used hibernate in persisting the data?  Is my logic correct?  Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly.  You must tell Hibernate how to store the data.  That is done by either adding annotations to the Java objects or via deployment descriptor.  You will have to, for example, declare one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.  From that point on, you could let the ORM handle everything: Creating the tables, storing and retrieving the data, etc.  You could (and probably should), however, optimize the database from SQL, i.e. create index tables or assign data types and THEN let the ORM handle the rest. You won't get around deciding how to map the data, though.

Answer (score 1):

At its core, it's about [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Data persistence and logic are two separate concerns. The application coder should not have to concern himself with what flavor of SQL the IT staff has decided to use this week, and how to translate between the different paradigms of relation entities and object hierarchy entities.

The DBA should also not need to concern himself with object ownership rules and other almost-leaky concerns from the business layer.

In reality, in larger systems, you rarely can be completely vendor-agnostic, and the DAO layer inevitably picks up some non-ORM-related queries for performance tweaks. Tools like Hibernate do the best they can to make these situations as rare and abstract as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using an ORM like (N)Hibernate just makes sure that you don't have to worry much about writing SQL queries, it helps you focus on the 'domain' (business logic).

However, it is required to have some understanding of the underlying DB (and sql) in order to be able to create performant apps. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia : Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) ? :)

To be more precise, an ORM allows you to use Objects directly bound to your Database.

For example, I have a Car, which has 4 object Door, each Door has a Color, each Color a Name.

With an ORM, I get my Car object from the Database. Then I go for a Car.GetDoors(), and I get a collection of my Doors, and for each one of them, I can use a Door.GetColor().GetColorName().

Which means that I didn't bother to write SQL queries to get the Doors from the Door Table, with a CarID, nor get a ColorName from the Color table with a colorID. An ORM thus allows me to write less code :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be writing a web-based application for a large company that could involve hundreds of thousands of objects of many different classes. You want to write all the business logic in object-oriented code, but these objects need persisting to an SQL database. Using ORM means you don't have to worry about how to convert to and from SQL, but can instead concentrate on implementing the actual application.

Answer (score 0):

Check this !  [hibernate-interview-questions-faqs](http://www.developersbook.com/hibernate/interview-questions/hibernate-interview-questions-faqs.php)